# Sorting json response using powershell scripting

Tags: json, sorting, powershell

I am making a REST API call and getting a json response in return. I want to get the highest string from the response.

```
$x = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $r
```

This returns something like this

```
    {
  "results": [
    {
      "uri": "h//foo/test.1.0.19.4.n"
    },
    {
      "uri": "h://foo/test.1.0.20.6.n"
    },
    {
      "uri": "h://foo/test.1.0.20.7.n"
    }
  ]
}
```

From this I want to extract `"test.1.0.20.7.n"`, this the largest when compared between `.19` and `.20` and when I compare the last one i want `.7` over `.6`

I have been trying to use

```
$X| Select uri |  Sort-Object uri
```

it just prints

```
test...
test...
test...
```

Comment: Hi, I guess you first need [`Convert-FromJson`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json) before `Select-Object`

Comment: Assuming that the `uri` values are valid URI's, you could do `$X |Select results |Sort-Object {(($_.uri -as [uri]).Segments[-1] -replace '.*(\d+)\.n$','$1') -as [int]}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by leveraging "custom" sort with an Expression as I blogged about [earlier](https://www.cupfighter.net/2014/02/custom-sort-a-list-of-objects-in-powershell). Following sample works for me:

```
$json = @"
    {
  "results": [
    {
      "uri": "h://foo/test.1.0.19.4.n"
    },
    {
      "uri": "h://foo/test.1.0.20.7.n"
    },
    {
      "uri": "h://foo/test.1.0.20.6.n"
    }
  ]
}
"@

$obj = ConvertFrom-Json $json

$obj.results | Sort-Object -Property @{Expression={[int]($_.uri -replace "\D", "")}} | select -Last 1
```

Output:

```
uri                    
---                    
h://foo/test.1.0.20.7.n
```

And with this dataset:

```
    {
  "results": [
    {
      "uri": "h://foo/test.1.0.19.4.n"
    },
    {
      "uri": "h://foo/test.1.1.5.7.n"
    },
    {
      "uri": "h://foo/test.1.2.20.1.n"
    },
    {
      "uri": "h://foo/test.1.0.20.7.n"
    },
    {
      "uri": "h://foo/test.1.0.20.6.n"
    }
  ]
}
```

The result is:

```
uri                    
---                    
h://foo/test.1.2.20.1.n
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks this solves the issue to get the highest. Had to change to [int64] if using really big numbers. Also,  From the output, is there a way I can just get "test.1.0.20.7.n" ?

Comment: Good to hear (so you should accept it as an answer). For the other part, use a RegEx or string operation (eg split or substring) but that's a new question.

Answer (score 1):

To provide an alternative to [Remko's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43239313/45375) that:

- Uses type `[version]` to achieve the desired sorting:

  - `[version]` performs the appropriate component-by-component comparison for sorting.
  - Aside from being a more direct implementation of the underlying concept, this has the advantage of not having to worry about overflowing an integer data type.
- Extracts only the substring of interest, such as `test.1.0.20.7.n`

```
# Parse sample JSON input into a PS custom object.
$objFromJson = @'
    {
  "results": [
    {
      "uri": "h://foo/test.1.0.19.4.n"
    },
    {
      "uri": "h://foo/test.1.0.20.7.n"
    },
    {
      "uri": "h://foo/test.1.0.20.6.n"
    }
  ]
}
'@ | ConvertFrom-Json

# Sort the results by the version-number-like tokens embedded in the `uri`
# property of the elements of the collection stored in the `.result` property,
# output the one with the highest version number, then remove
# the URL path prefix with `Split-Path`
$objFromJson.results | 
 Sort-Object -Descending {[version] ($_.uri -replace '^.+(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+).+$', '$1')} |
   Select-Object -First 1 |
     Split-Path -Leaf -Path { $_.uri }
```

The above yields:

```
test.1.0.20.7.n
```

In the `-replace` operation above:

- regex `^.+(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+).+$` matches the entire URI and captures the version-like part (e.g., `1.0.19.4`) in a capture group,
- whose value (`$1`) is then used as the replacement string, which effectively returns just the version-like part, which the `[version]` cast then converts to that type.

@Remko suggests making the regex more flexible, in case you need to match version-like strings with *fewer* components. In practice, casting from a string to `[version]` is limited to 2 to 4 components (e.g., strings `1.2`, `1.2.3`, and `1.2.3.4` work, but `1` and `1.2.3.4.5` don't), which you can model with the following regex:
`'^.+((\d+\.){1,3}\d+).+$'`

If your version-like strings have *more* components, you must implement your own sorting (Remko's answer may work, if the numbers that result from interpreting all digits in the version-like string as a single integer don't grow too large).